# Simplest conjunction (intersection) code

Tags: c#, linq, intersection

I have two arrays and I wnat the simplest way of knowing if they have elements in common. So actually this question have to questions.

```
string[] countries1 = new string[] { "USA", "Uruguay", "India", "UK"};  
string[] countries2 = new string[] { "Urguay", "Argentina", "Brasil", "Chile" };  
foreach (string country in countries1)
    if (countries2.Contains(country))  
        return true;  
return false;
```

1. What's the simplest linq query that will let me know if any of the `country1` countries is also in the `country2` array?
2. What's the simplest linq query that will return an array of every repeated country?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) `var isIntersection = countries1.Intersect(countries2).Any();`

2) `var intersectedCountries = countries1.Intersect(countries2);`

Comment: In the first example there is an extra bracket!

Answer (score 2):

For intersection between countries 1 and 2:

`countries1.Intersect(countries2).ToArray()`

Comment: Why should you use `Count` method? `Any` is better in my opinion. :)

Comment: I had missunderstood the "counting" question. It was counting the repeated items within the same array. Actually, the Any method is the best choice in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Adilson's answer covers your question #2, and for question #1

> What's the simplest linq query that will let me know if any of the country1 countries is also in the country2 array?

You would do:

```
countries1.Intersect(countries2).Any();
```

The `.Any()` will return true on the first instance of a match, whereas `.Count()` or `.ToArray()` will iterate the entire list.

Answer (score 1):

With LINQ:

```
var commonCountries = countries1.Intersect(countries2);

if (commonCountries.Any())
    // There are common countries.
```

But, this doesn't take into consideration string casing etc. What you may want to do, is chuck together a quick `IEqualityComparer<string>`:

```
public class OrdinalStringComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public bool Equals(string s1, string s2)
    {
        return string.Equals(s1, s2, StringComparison.OrdinalCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
    public int GetHashCode(string str)
    {
        return (str == null) ? 0 : str.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then pass that in with your `Intersect` call:

```
var commonCountries = countries1.Intersect(countries2, new OrdinalStringComparer());
```